# Dailymotion url shows adds before starting video

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am using dailymotion partner program also uploaded video form my application but its showing advertisement before actual video starts.
 Is there any way to avoid it? I avoid info by info=0.

Also autoplay=1 not playing video automatically on some android devices?

here is my url for video.

http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/k5I37tfOYjxdgub0Oyu?related=0&logo=0&info=0

this url avoid related video and video information but most important to avoid advertisement.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to remove advertisement from a dailymotion video. Dailymotion, like other video sharing platforms, has the need to cover its expenditure in order to offer this service to you. This is why advertisments are automatically displayed with videos.

About the autoplay issue: most mobile devices prevent videos from being played automatically, this is why `autoplay` parameter may not work on some devices. Those devices require an user interaction to first play the video. Please read the following for more detailed info: [Dailymotion embedded player on iOS devices (HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372401/dailymotion-embedded-player-on-ios-devices-html5)
(and next time, please remember you should ask one question per post)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem with ads. You can remove the advertisements by going to the video settings (the edit pencil icon next to the video) then scroll down to the monetization section. Click the "I agree" checkbox to enable monetization. Once you have done that there is a checkbox to remove ads from this video (there will be a warning that if you remove ads, you won't receive revenue for this video). Then save your changes. This worked for me.

As Dailymotion indicated, it is not possible to autoplay videos on mobile devices (due to possible data surcharges). The user must play the video on purpose. This is true for any video, not just Dailymotion.