# Dailymotion auto play not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, dailymotion-api

I have a video for website intro. I need it to be auto play .. its works fine on the desktop. but On `IOS (Iphone4 and Iphone 6) Android (Samsung note 10 , note 1,2,3,4)` Not working on all of these.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="width:100% !important;height:100vh !important;" width="100vw" height="100vh" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/kKhw1NdehXdXzhdjrJ5?autoplay=1&chromeless=0&quality=240&related=0&webkit-playsinline=1&ended=videEnded" allowfullscreen autoplay ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question has been answered here already: [Dailymotion embedded player on iOS devices (HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372401/dailymotion-embedded-player-on-ios-devices-html5)

Basically, mobile devices prevent videos from being played automatically, this is why it's not playing with your code. Those devices require an user interaction to first play the video.