# dailymotion api initial play

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, dailymotion-api

I'm trying to use the dailymotion api and I'm having problems with iphone and chrome on a mac.

In chrome, I have the autoplay set to true and it should work but it doesn't. I get a "play" button for flash on top when I load the player. And I cannot use the play api. Once I click on this button, I can use the api normally. The html version does not work at all on chrome.

Also on iPhone, I know that the autoplay should not work and it's normal. However if I use the api to do a play, it display another button inside the container that I need to click or the video won't start. Again once this initial click is done, play/pause using the api is working normally.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test dailymotion</title>
    <script src="https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="player-dailymotion"></div>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <button id="pause">Pause</button>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Give time to load dailymotion script
setTimeout(function() {
    DM.init({
    apiKey: '',
    status: false, // check login status
    cookie: true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
});

var player = DM.player(
    document.querySelector('#player-dailymotion'), 
    {
        video: 'x1safo9',
        width: '400px',
        height: '200px',
        params: {
            autoplay: 1,
            chromeless: 1
        }
    }
);

document.querySelector('#play').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('click on play');
    player.play();
});

document.querySelector('#pause').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('click on pause');
    player.pause();
});

}, 1000);


</script>
</html>
```

example on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uq8gftcy/1/

Is there a way to use the api to start the video the first time on iPhone ? And why autoplay is not working on my chrome mac ?

[Update] I found an article talking about a chrome update and they are now blocking all flash content by default. How can I use dailymotion html version then ?

Comment: Actually chrome is now blocking all flash content: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/08/google-chrome-will-block-auto-playing-flash-ads-from-september-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two issues are normal behaviors of the video player:

- autoplay on chrome: chrome blocks flash player under a certain size, so a user interaction is needed to play the video. Try to set a bigger player (like 738x432), you'll get the expected behavior.
- on iOS: this is an iOS restriction. Calling play() from a button outside the player iframe is not considered as a real user interaction, so you must wait for the user to touch the player's start screen. See [Dailymotion embedded player on iOS devices (HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372401/dailymotion-embedded-player-on-ios-devices-html5#answer-24447447) for more detailed info.

You can check other video providers, the behavior is the same as it is dependant on the OS / browser's choices.